# Regex Vmware SDK results

Tags: regex

I want to parse this output. It's the result of an api call to vmware SDK

[{type:Datastore,val:datastore-83,_value:datastore-83},{type:Datastore,val:datastore-84,_value:datastore-84},{type:Datastore,val:datastore-85,_value:datastore-85},{type:Datastore,val:datastore-88,_value:datastore-88},{type:Datastore,val:datastore-237,_value:datastore-237},{type:Datastore,val:datastore-705,_value:datastore-705},{type:Datastore,val:datastore-706,_value:datastore-706},{type:Datastore,val:datastore-707,_value:datastore-707},{type:Datastore,val:datastore-89,_value:datastore-89}]

My Goal is to extract only the datastore id's for exemple "datastore-83".

At the end i want a list with all the datastore id's for exemple :

datastore-705,datastore-89 etc ...

What is the best way to achieve that ? I can only use regex or maybe with some javascript and Nashorn.

I'm not very good with regex. I tried /datastore-\d*/ but in that case i have the only first occurence. How can i get all the datastore id's from this ouput ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that you have some output that you can pipe into a script or a program. You could use **awk** for this like:

```
awk '{ while (match($0,/val:(datastore-[0-9]+)/,a)){ \
          printf("%s%s", (i++?",":""), a[1]); \
          $0=substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH) \
       } \
     }'
```

So now you can:

```
echo '[{type:Datastore,val:datastore-83,_value  ..... | awk '{ while...
```